# to solve non-linear constrained problem in python using l1 minimization

Tags: python, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am Currently working on some optimization problem which involves non-linear constraint. The problem is as follows :

[image]

I need to perform either of the two minimizations shown in image in python. I found library scipy which has optimize.minimize() function but I am unable to fit in the Non-Linear constraint using scipy.NonLinearConstraint. Can anyone guide? How to solve this? Is there also a way to solve it using some homotopy function given in any of the libraries? I have tried (adding constraint for the alternative one)as:

```
con = lambda A,x,y : np.matmul(A,x) - y
nlc = NonlinearConstraint(con, 0, epsilon)
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-linear constrained? I interpret the *upper variant* as linear-optimization problem minimizing l1-norm. This can be easily transformed into a simple LP which allows poly-time global-optimal solutions. Something which is probably hard to beat by all other (general) approaches, especially general nonlinear opt. Using nonlinear opt, you should reason first about differentiability of l1-norms which will not be compatible with most of those solvers assumptions.

Comment: @sascha : the second equation is subject to non-linear constraint which is mentioned as alternative way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally could solve the above optimization by using spgl1 solver in python. It can be used as shown below:

```
from spgl1 import spgl1, spg_bp, spg_bpdn

#x01 = psueodinverse of A multiplied by y  
x,resid,grad,info = spgl1(A, y, tau = tau, sigma = epsilon, x0 = x01, iter_lim = 150)
```

one can refer about the above solver at [github link](https://github.com/drrelyea/spgl1) or [pypi link](https://pypi.org/project/spgl1/)